# How to get multiple copies of a cell in a single row by n-number?

Tags: excel, copy, repeat, vba

I would like to use vba code that can sort this problem out.

I have a row and i want multiple copies of each cell in the same row. It needs to copy the cell by n-numbers. In row 1 will be the information to be copied. and in row 2 the n-number.

So the example:

Input: (say the n-number = 3)

- John
- Hendrik
- Sara

Output:

- John
- John
- John
- Hendrik
- Hendrik
- Hendrik
- Hendrik
- Sara
- Sara
- Sara
  ....

Hope someone could help me out!

Comment: I presume your examples here are transposed? Do you want the new information to overwrite the existing information? What have you tried? Do you have any VBA, or programming experience? I suggest you read the values into an array, then iterate over that array and paste the contents of the array into the appropriate number of cells using the resize and offset methods of the range object. If this makes absolutely no sense, let me know, I'll give you some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyInAWeirdWay()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim currentCopyRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    currentCopyRow = 1

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For k = 1 To sh.Cells(i, 2)
            sh.Cells(currentCopyRow, 3).Value = sh.Cells(i, 1).Value
            currentCopyRow = currentCopyRow + 1
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is kind of what i want only i want the n-numbers to be starting in B1 and the copy-list staring from C1 so everything is seperate. i cant upload a image because i dont have much reputation :(.

Comment: Got it. Give me a few minutes

Comment: @MicheldeWinter, I revised the answer. This should work for you

Comment: Joseph4tw THANKS VERY MUCH!!

Comment: @MicheldeWinter glad to help! If this solves your answer, do you mind accepting my answer by clicking the checkbox next to my answer?